# servlet api version and scope in maven

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, jetty

I'm adding a filter to my spring web application.  I'm using the jdk for development so I had to include a servlet-api jar to get my project to compile.  My understanding is that the servlet api and its implementation should be provided by jetty (the container I'm developing on) and tomcat (prod server).  When I add the following snippet to my pom.xml my project compiles successfully.  My environment setup is the following:

Java 1.6 jdk
Jetty 8.1.4.v20120524
Spring 3.2.0.Release

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

However when I run my application locally the server throws the following exception upon start up:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318
)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:492)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:312)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:778)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:262)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:364)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:516)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2013-09-17 21:19:35.038:WARN:/:unavailable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318
)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:492)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:312)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:778)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:262)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:364)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:516)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at     org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Comment: Try adding `<scope>provided</scope>` to the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

First concerning the servlet-api I think it's not needed that your project has dependencies on jetty, it would be better to have your depencies on the api itself and have it scoped as provided as already mentionned.

Something like this for example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Second concerning the error that your are having, it looks like you are missing some dependencies, did you add jersey multipart ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>$your_version_of_jersey</version>
</dependency>
```